# Is it possible to have more than one complete directed graphs? And if yes, how many? I found a formula but I can't make sense of it.

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

### 3<sup>C<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup></sup>  = 3<sup>[num of arcs in undirected graph for some reason]</sup>

Is the formula I found relating to this, I would imagine it means for every node you can either have an arc pointing to it, from it, or both ways, hence the 3, then I have no Idea why they wouldn't use

#### n*(n-1)

being the num of arcs in a directed graph.

Comment: Let me suggest you take a look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on a few points: **Your question should be clear without the title.** *After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=2$ and call the points $A$ and $B$.  An undirected complete graph has $\frac 12\cdot 2 \cdot 1=1$ edge.  The text points out that you have $3=3^1=3^{2 \choose 2}$ complete directed graphs where it allows one edge from $A$ to $B$ alone, one edge from $B$ to $A$ alone, or one edge in each direction.  You are thinking you need to start with two edges, one in each direction.  The choices of whether to retain the two edges are not independent.  If you use your exponent you get $3^2=9$ different graphs, but  I can't find that many.

Comment: thank you, I got it now, take total number of pairs (basically no. to edges in undirected graph) and take 3 possible outcomes for each one of them. thanks a ton. I haven't responded as quickly as i needed to